Can I order by a conditional combination of fields in MySQL?
Example Fiddle
    CREATE TABLE Demo (JobID INT(11), Status VARCHAR(250), InvoiceStatus VARCHAR(250));
    
    INSERT INTO Demo (JobID, Status, InvoiceStatus) VALUES (1, "Active", NULL), (2, "Cancelled", NULL), (3, "Invoiced", "Not Paid"), (4, "Invoiced", "Paid"), (5, "No Invoice Required", "Paid"), (6, "Active", NULL);
    SELECT * FROM Demo ORDER BY FIELD (Status, "Cancelled") ASC, JobID

The desired output is to have the rows ordered by JobID, but have any jobs where the Status is "Cancelled" at the end, and any jobs where the Status is "Invoiced" and the InvoiceStatus is "Paid" also at the end, but before Cancelled jobs.
I found out how to get "Cancelled" at the end with ORDER BY Field(), but I'm not sure how to apply a similar thing only when two fields match the given values ("Invoiced" and "Paid").
So with the above examples, the desired output would be
JobID   Status              InvoiceStatus
-----------------------------------------
1       Active              NULL
3       Invoiced            Not Paid
5       No Invoice Required Paid
6       Active              NULL
4       Invoiced            Paid
2       Cancelled           NULL


The order instruction accepts expressions like if(a>1,b,c+3), and case...end.

SELECT * FROM Demo 
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN Status='Cancelled' THEN 2
    WHEN Status='Invoiced' AND InvoiceStatus='Paid' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END,
  JobId;


I had no idea that it was possibly to do it like this, thanks! Are there performance implications using CASE? The Status field is indexed which will definitely help though :)

The expression cannot use an index on the Status field, so that doesn't help. The performance of the query will have to sort the result, but it won't be significantly different from the solution you showed in your post above.
